# Small C Program

Tags: c

Could someone explain the output please

```
int main()
{
    int a[2][2]={{1,2},{1,2}};

    printf("a[0]:  %d\n",a[0]);
    printf("a[1]:  %d\n",a[1]);
    printf("Diff:  %d\n",a[1] - a[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

> a[0]:  -214886704
>   a[1]:  -214886696
>   Diff:  2

Comment: And the other homework question is? Or perhaps run it

Comment: There is a copy-paste typo on the second line: `a[0]` should be `a[1]`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @redFIVE not even close

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to print the address of the arrays, instead of the values. Use `a[i][j]` to access the elements of two dimensional arrays.

You should increase the warning level of your compiler, it would give you an explicit warning on what you're doing wrong:

```
lol.c:5:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
lol.c:6:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("a[1]:  %d\n",a[0]);
 ^
lol.c:7:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("Diff:  %d\n",a[1] - a[0]);
 ^
```

Comment: you mean gcc *.c isnt good enough?!

Comment: @redFIVE It's better to use warning since they can help point out some dumb mistakes or typos that could compile without warnings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he was sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

In-order to access the element in a 2D array you need to give row and column

```
a[0][0] and a[0][1]
```

Actually `a[0]` gives you the address of the array. The below code might give you what you were trying to do using the array address

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[2][2]={{1,2},{1,2}};

    printf("a[0]:  %p\n",(void *)a[0]); /* Address of first row */
    printf("a[1]:  %p\n",(void *)a[1]); /* Address of second row */
    printf("Diff:  %d\n",(a[1] - a[0])); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the cast to `(void *)` is not needed.

Comment: @iharob ok thanks . Just kept it there to bring it to the OP's notice that `%p` expects `void *`

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the address of the array `a[0]` which has to be `unsigned long int` in your system with the `%d` specifier which accepts `int` when you print `unsigned long int` with the `%d` specifier it prints only the first 32 bits of the value, `%d` is for signed `int` therefore the value could be negative.

If you want to print the value you need to access the element with this syntax `a[n][m]` for the `m`th element of the `n`th array.

If you want to print the address of the array you need the `%p` specifier.

Your last line, gives `2` because that is the difference between the addresses of `a[0]` and `a[1]`, virtual addresses are represented by integers.

Comment: The integer is not overflowing, and -214886704 is not the minimum value for int.

Comment: It just display the address of the row in its signed decimal notation (or just its first 4 bytes on 64bit systems). The minimum value for int is -2,147,483,648 , not even close to -214,886,704.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.